# When to use unit testing or snapshot testing with jest and enzyme?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I am starting to write tests to my react app with jest and enzyme for native and for the frontend and I want to have a clear Idea when to use snapshot tests and when to use unit testing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snapshots are a tool used in unit testing. If you don't use snapshots, then you end up with large chunks of test data in your unit test code. For example, imagine you are testing a function that returns a hundred lines of text, like a blog post. One way would be to have an `expect(blogPost).toBe(thisHugeStringOfManyLines)`. We can use snapshots to easily manage large chunks of test data. Jest creates separate files for test data, and provides an easy diffing mechanism to see what parts of data has changed. In case of react and enzyme, the testing data is JSX.

Comment: I think this is helpful I'll take this into consideration when start writing my tests, Thanks